# Received an incorrect review from a conference (a review for a different paper). What should I do?

Tags: peer-review, conference

I've submitted a paper to a computer vision conference (a top one), and recently recieved reviews from the reviewers. An issue was that one of the reviewers provided an incorrect review (i.e., a review meant for another paper than ours).

At the moment, I do not know which Area Chair (AC) manages my submission. All I can do is to contact the Program Chair (PC). Should I contact PC about this before submitting my rebuttal (i.e., responses to the reviews)?

The context is that my advisor told me that if I contact PC for this reason, it might be interference. So I was kind of scard and this is why I ask a question here. Also, it might not be completely obvious to others that the review is an incorrect one (althoguh it is completely clear to me).

Comment: And what has that advisor of yours recommended to do instead?

Answer (score 37):

> I do not know which AC manages my submission. All I can do is to contact PC.

Therefore...

> Should I contact PC about this before submitting my rebuttal

**Yes**, or more broadly: use whatever contact information you have for the organizers. There is no point in rebutting an editorial mistake.

Comment: Sending a formal "rebuttal" may cause even more confusion, if somebody (e.g. a secretary or administrator) thinks it came from the real author of the paper. You don't *have* a review to respond to yet - you just have some mail that was sent to the wrong person.

Answer (score 19):

> My advisor told me that if I contact PC for this reason, it might be interference.

Your advisor is mistaken. If you had contacted the Program Committee chair trying to influence the refereeing process - yes, that would have been inappropriate. But it is actually very common for authors to contact PC chairs, for a variety of reason:

- Problems with the paper submission system.
- Delays in replies.
- Requests for clarifications regarding the call for papers.
- Questions regarding the submissibility of papers
- Requests for deadline extensions (not saying that these are granted though...)

so it's not considered inappropriate in general.

Also remember that *program committee chairs typically don't referee/review submissions themselves*, so you're not contacting the person who's reviewing your work, nor interfering with that review.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up!